# NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'metricFilter' available

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am using spring boot 1.4.2 with `[spring-boot-legacy 1.1.0][1]` in order to deploy to weblogic 10.3 (java 6 / servlet 2.5) .....Every thins is working fine on tomcat 7 when I comment the metric filter part ... I only face issues when I deploy to weblogic .... So I returned back to tomcat in order to run it ... I uncommented the metric filter,  When I try to deploy my application it gives :

```
SEVERE: Exception starting filter metricFilter
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'metricFilter' available
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:680)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1183)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:284)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1087)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.initDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:326)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.initFilterBean(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:235)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.GenericFilterBean.init(GenericFilterBean.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:285)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:266)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4981)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5683)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.start(ManagerServlet.java:1320)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.start(HTMLManagerServlet.java:683)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.doPost(HTMLManagerServlet.java:209)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.CsrfPreventionFilter.doFilter(CsrfPreventionFilter.java:136)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:607)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:1025)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:445)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1115)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2555)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2544)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

here is my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
     http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>com.my.Application</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.boot.legacy.context.web.SpringBootContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>metricFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>metricFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

        <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextAttribute</param-name>
            <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext.ROOT</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>messageDispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextAttribute</param-name>
            <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext.ROOT</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>messageDispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/ws/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <display-name>IPOMS Online Channel</display-name>

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>15</session-timeout>
    </session-config>

    <!-- The Usual Welcome File List -->
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

I have this is my build.gradle :

```
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-legacy:1.1.0.RELEASE')
```

here is the code of the `MetricFilterAutoConfiguration` in the `spring-boot-legacy` project in which the metric filter bean is defined:

```
/*
 * Copyright 2012-2013 the original author or authors.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

package org.springframework.boot.legacy.context.web;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.Servlet;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponseWrapper;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricRepositoryAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.CounterService;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.GaugeService;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigureAfter;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.ConditionalOnBean;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.ConditionalOnClass;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.ConditionalOnMissingClass;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.Ordered;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.util.StopWatch;
import org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping;
import org.springframework.web.util.UrlPathHelper;

/**
 * {@link EnableAutoConfiguration Auto-configuration} that records Servlet interactions
 * with a {@link CounterService} and {@link GaugeService}.
 * 
 * @author Dave Syer
 * @author Phillip Webb
 */
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnBean({ CounterService.class, GaugeService.class })
@ConditionalOnClass({ Servlet.class, MetricRepositoryAutoConfiguration.class })
@ConditionalOnMissingClass("javax.servlet.ServletRegistration")
@AutoConfigureAfter({
        MetricRepositoryAutoConfiguration.class,
        org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricFilterAutoConfiguration.class })
public class MetricFilterAutoConfiguration {

    private static final int UNDEFINED_HTTP_STATUS = 999;

    private static final String UNKNOWN_PATH_SUFFIX = "/unmapped";

    @Autowired
    private CounterService counterService;

    @Autowired
    private GaugeService gaugeService;

    @Bean
    public Filter metricFilter() {
        return new MetricsFilter();
    }

    /**
     * Filter that counts requests and measures processing times.
     */
    @Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
    private final class MetricsFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

        @Override
        protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request,
                HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws ServletException,
                IOException {
            UrlPathHelper helper = new UrlPathHelper();
            String suffix = helper.getPathWithinApplication(request);
            StopWatch stopWatch = new StopWatch();
            stopWatch.start();
            MetricsFilterResponseWrapper wrapper = new MetricsFilterResponseWrapper(
                    response);
            try {
                chain.doFilter(request, wrapper);
            }
            finally {
                stopWatch.stop();
                int status = getStatus(wrapper);
                Object bestMatchingPattern = request
                        .getAttribute(HandlerMapping.BEST_MATCHING_PATTERN_ATTRIBUTE);
                if (bestMatchingPattern != null) {
                    suffix = bestMatchingPattern.toString().replaceAll("[{}]", "-");
                }
                else if (HttpStatus.valueOf(status).is4xxClientError()) {
                    suffix = UNKNOWN_PATH_SUFFIX;
                }
                String gaugeKey = getKey("response" + suffix);
                MetricFilterAutoConfiguration.this.gaugeService.submit(gaugeKey,
                        stopWatch.getTotalTimeMillis());
                String counterKey = getKey("status." + getStatus(wrapper) + suffix);
                MetricFilterAutoConfiguration.this.counterService.increment(counterKey);
            }
        }

        private int getStatus(MetricsFilterResponseWrapper response) {
            try {
                return response.getStatus();
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                return UNDEFINED_HTTP_STATUS;
            }
        }

        private String getKey(String string) {
            // graphite compatible metric names
            String value = string.replace("/", ".");
            value = value.replace("..", ".");
            if (value.endsWith(".")) {
                value = value + "root";
            }
            if (value.startsWith("_")) {
                value = value.substring(1);
            }
            return value;
        }
    }

    private class MetricsFilterResponseWrapper extends HttpServletResponseWrapper {

        private int status;

        public MetricsFilterResponseWrapper(HttpServletResponse response) {
            super(response);
        }

        public int getStatus() {
            return status;
        }

        @Override
        public void setStatus(int sc) {
            setStatus(sc, null);
        }

        @Override
        public void setStatus(int status, String sm) {
            this.status = status;
            super.setStatus(status, sm);
        }
    }

}
```

what else do I need to avoid this error

Comment: Are you sure you have "metricFilter" bean in your  application context?

Comment: @ali4j .. kindly check the code of `MetricFilterAutoConfiguration ` that I added to the question

Comment: I would suggest you to insert a break point in the line ```return new MetricsFilter();``` and then run the application in debug mode. If it does not reach this line at startup (before failing), then the autoconfiguration is not being done and that would probably be due to one of ```@ConditionalOnBean({ CounterService.class, GaugeService.class })
@ConditionalOnClass({ Servlet.class, MetricRepositoryAutoConfiguration.class })
@ConditionalOnMissingClass("javax.servlet.ServletRegistration")"``` conditions not being met.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably I figured out the problem ... tomcat 7 is actually servlet 3.0 container not servlet 2.5 ... thus the `@ConditionalOnMissingClass("javax.servlet.ServletRegistration")` is not satisfied as this class is there in servlet 3.0 ... so the bean is not created ... I was about to check on tomcat 6 ... but didn't have time

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I understand from [spring documents](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-class-conditions), “MetricFilterAutoConfiguration” class is not included in the configuration and that's because at least one of the conditional annotations is not met.

Comment: `MetricRepositoryAutoConfiguration` is in `spring-boot-legacy` jar not in spring core ... I included its code in the question

Comment: By "is not included" I mean those beans which are declared in this configuration class [MetricFilterAutoConfiguration"] are not included in the context and for this reason you are getting "NoSuchBeanDefinitionException" exception.